# Contact us form - displayed when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I'm trying to get a button to run a JavaScript function that prints out a contact form for my website, but it's not working. The button comes up, but when you click it, the form doesn't show up.

Here is the code in my JavaScript page:

```
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    '<div class="container">'
    +'<form action="/action_page.php">'
    +'<label for="fname">First Name</label>'
    +'<input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your 
    name..">'

    + '<label for="lname">Last Name</label>'
    +'<input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last 
    name..">'

    +'<label for="country">Country</label>'
    +'<select id="country" name="country">'
    +'<option value="australia">Australia</option>'
    +'<option value="canada">Canada</option>'
    +'<option value="usa">USA</option>'
    +'</select>'

    +'<label for="subject">Subject</label>'
    +'<textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." 
    style="height:200px"></textarea>'

    +'<input type="submit" value="Submit">'
    +'</form>'
    +'</div>';
    }
```

Here's the code in the Contact Us page:

```
    <button onclick="myFunction()">If you have any questions, concerns, or 
    comments please click here to send us an email: </button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

I've tried doing it without the concatenation and that doesn't work either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `The button comes up, but when you click it` Which button? I don't see any click handlers either...

Comment: I apologize, I'm newer to stack overflow and I'm taking my first Web Development class this semester so I'm still learning. Can I add a photo to my post?

Comment: Please post all the relevant code *as text* in your question - don't use images of code alone

Comment: I did, that code was text

Comment: but I did add a photo to show the button you were asking about

Comment: You have new lines in the strings

Comment: Looks like your JS syntax is invalid - the line break between `Your` ande `name..` (among others) in a string literal will result in a `SyntaxError`

Comment: Is there a way I can fix it so its usable? I essentially was putting CSS syntax (a contact form) into a JS function (the button) so that when you click the button the contact form is supposed to appear for the user to input their information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *htmlString* is not properly concatenated. I also prefer JavaScript to bind the function instead of inline event handler:

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    '<div class="container">'
    +'<form action="/action_page.php">'
    +'<label for="fname">First Name</label>'
    +'<input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">'

    + '<label for="lname">Last Name</label>'
    +'<input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">'

    +'<label for="country">Country</label>'
    +'<select id="country" name="country">'
    +'<option value="australia">Australia</option>'
    +'<option value="canada">Canada</option>'
    +'<option value="usa">USA</option>'
    +'</select>'

    +'<label for="subject">Subject</label>'
    +'<textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>'

    +'<input type="submit" value="Submit">'
    +'</form>'
    +'</div>';
    }
    
document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click',myFunction);
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">If you have any questions, concerns, or 
comments please click here to send us an email: </button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Though I prefer using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to from the *htmlString* which is more cleaner.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    `<div class="container">'
    <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>'
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>
    
    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form></div>`;
}
 document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click',myFunction);
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">If you have any questions, concerns, or 
comments please click here to send us an email: </button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice and the help, much appreciated!

Comment: instead use `+` use one string with this char `

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a function to create the HTML.

```js
// Get the contact form button and add an event listener for the click
document.getElementById("show-contact-form").addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  // When the button is clicked, remove the hidden class, which will show the contact form
  document.getElementById("contact-form").classList.remove("hidden");

  // Hide the contact us button
  this.classList.add("hidden");
});
```

```css
/* Used to hide content */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Create the form with straight HTML -->
<div id="contact-form" class="container hidden">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>
    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

<!-- Button to show contact form -->
<button id="show-contact-form">Contact us</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly working, there an only issue of unnecessary `enter` like you enter in `placeholder`.

**checkout the example below**

```
function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
        '<div class="container">'
        +'<form action="/action_page.php">'
        +'<label for="fname">First Name</label>'
        +'<input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">'

        + '<label for="lname">Last Name</label>'
        +'<input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">'

        +'<label for="country">Country</label>'
        +'<select id="country" name="country">'
        +'<option value="australia">Australia</option>'
        +'<option value="canada">Canada</option>'
        +'<option value="usa">USA</option>'
        +'</select>'

        +'<label for="subject">Subject</label>'
        +'<textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>'

        +'<input type="submit" value="Submit">'
        +'</form>'
        +'</div>';
    }
```